# How can I setup a DNS server for a subdomain behind a dynamic IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm working on a secure/isolated service that manages TLS certificates using the ACME protocol. The server needs to respond with a TXT record on a specific subdomain. This server won't service requests from the general public, but it needs to be publicly available.

`CNAME` records are permitted and can be followed.

Our TLS management server that hosts the dynamic `TXT` record is running Bind9, and is located in a place where dynamic IPs are the only option.

The domain's main DNS records are on a public DNS server with the registrar. We've successfully set up a subdomain that is updated using dynamic DNS, but it seems that the Dynamic DNS provider doesn't allow `NS` records.

So at the registrar we have:

```
domain.com          A   xx.xx.xx.xx
www.domain.com      A   xx.xx.xx.xx
dynamic.domain.com  NS  dynamic.provider.com
```

At the dynamic provider we have:

```
dynamic.domain.com  A yy.yy.yy.yy
```

At our TLS bot server, we have Bind9 running as the authority for `dynamic.domain.com` with a text `TXT` record:

```
test  TXT     "A nice Test."
```

So the desired result is that, from anywhere on the internet, you should be able to run `dig TXT test.dynamic.domain.com` and get `A nice Test.`.

This seems to be failing at the dynamic DNS provider:

```
dig TXT test.dynamic.domain.com
```

just gives:

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
dynamic.domain.com. 2208    IN  SOA dynamic.provider.com.
```

Is the only way forward to setup an `NS` record at the dynamic DNS provider (ie. switch providers to one that supports `NS` records or roll our own)? Or is there a workaround using `CNAME` records or `A` records to get this to work?

Comment: Why do you require ACME DNS challenge, instead of HTTP (or TLS-ALPN) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out how to make it work:

You need two subdomains: one to act as the dynamic `A` record, and one to point to the internal DNS service. Both get `NS` records at the registrar.

So at the registrar, the records look like this:

```
CNAME _acme-challenge.domain.com => tls.robert.domain.com
NS    dynamic.domain.com => dynamic.provider.nameservers
NS    robert.domain.com => ns.dynamic.domain.com
```

At the dynamic provider:

```
A ns.dynamic.domain.com => yy.yy.yy.yy (dynamic IP)
```

On the TLS bot server, in Bind:

```
$ORIGIN robert.domain.com.
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
robert.domain.com.  IN SOA  robert.domain.com. domains.domain.com. (
                                21         ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                                )
        NS      ns.dynamic.domain.com. ; Dynamic A record to self
tls     TXT     "A nice Test."
```

With that setup:

```
dig TXT _acme-challenge.domain.com
```

Produces:

```
tls.robert.domain.com. 14199 IN TXT "A nice Test."
```

... from anywhere.

**UPDATE:** A previous minor issue has been fixed, and the above answer has been edited. There are no longer any caveats. I welcome constructive feedback on any potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

You do not. Seriously. This is highly problemtic

if the need arises, ther are 2 possible workarounds:

- Use a vpn to a proxy VPS. I run into a similar situation, and all my traffic is routed through a US proxy server.
- Use a cloudflare zero trust tunnel. This essentially is a gateway you run locally that connects outbound to cloudflare.

In your case: scenario 1 - I pay 7 USD per month for a mikrotik vps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to use a cloudflare dns service or something like that, which has records for your acme workload. The benefit of it, is that will be available everywhere.https://www.cloudflare.com/application-services/products/dns/

Comment: Yes and no - if it is a pure dynanic ip without any blocking and you can live with hitting the wrong IP at times after a change - sure. Otherwise Cloudflare runs the same problem - you just hide it behind proxies that - incidentally - can not cache in this case.

Answer (score -2):

To set up a DNS server for a subdomain on a dynamic IP, use a Dynamic DNS service. Sign up with a provider, and install their client on your server to update the IP dynamically. Configure your DNS records to point the subdomain to the Dynamic DNS hostname. This ensures your subdomain stays connected, even with a changing IP address